# Bash Script to Wait for Part of Process

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run a program in the command line using a bash script. This program is really simple. I call it from the command line as `x` then feed it `1`, `filename`, `5`, `6`, `7` *but* I'm having a bit of trouble with:

1. feeding the right inputs at the right times, i.e. waiting to input the 5 until after the process(es) started by inputting 1 have finished
2. making sure that the inputs are actually getting to the program itself.

The program requests the inputs after it gets started, and then I can enter them from the command line, so I thought I could do that with a bash script. (It's my very first bash script. I didn't even "Hello world" before tackling this.)

I've tried using a `wait` and looked at `until` and things like that. Any suggestions from any of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*I cannot comment yet, so posting it as an answer, however incomplete, since OP didn't post enough data.*</sub>

You probably want to look into `expect`. It's a scripting language on it's own, but can be mixed with `bash` (although discouraged AFAIK). In a simplest form it works like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
expect "Prompt: "
send "my input\r"
expect eof
```

`\r` means `return` (I think), simply an <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

So, for example `expect` script for your program could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
expect "Provide 1: "
send "1\r

expect "Provide filename: "
send "foobar.txt\r"

expect "Provide 5: "
send "5\r"
# and so on...
expect eof
```

Please provide the code you have so far and example output prompts from your program "x", so we can tailor the answer to your needs.

Comment: Expect worked great! Thanks! I had to figure out a little bit about wildcards and such, but it worked quite well.